# AJAX Form not validating

Tags: php, ajax, forms

I'm very new to AJAX and PHP, so I probably missed something silly. I have been following a tutorial for AJAX Form validation and I have the same code as the guy, but it's not working for me. I checked 10 times for spelling mistakes. The point of the code is to validate the data written in the input field and redirect the user to another page if given the correct value.

The index.html:

```js
const form = {
  name: document.getElementById("name"),
  submit: document.getElementById("submit")
}

form.submit.addEventListener('click', function() {
  const request = new XMLHttpRequest();

  request.onload = () => {
    let responseObj = null;

    try {
      responseObj = JSON.parse(request.responseText);
    } catch (e) {
      console.error('Could not parse JSON!');
    }

    if (responseObj) {
      handleResponse(responseObj);
    }
  };

  const requestData = `name=${form.name.value}`;
  console.log(requestData);
  request.open('post', 'check-login.php');
  request.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
  request.send(requestData);
})

function handleResponse(responseObj) {
  if (responseObj.ok) {
    location.href = "dashboard.html";
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <title>Form Validation</title>
</head>

<body>

  <div class="form">
    <input type="text" id="name">
    <button type="submit" id="submit">Submit</button>
  </div>

  </div>
  <script>
  </script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-MrcW6ZMFYlzcLA8Nl+NtUVF0sA7MsXsP1UyJoMp4YLEuNSfAP+JcXn/tWtIaxVXM" crossorigin="anonymous">
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

The php code:

```
<?php

    $name = isset($_POST['name']) ? $_POST['name'] : '';

    $ok = true;
    $messages = array();

    if ( !isset($name) || empty($name) ) {
        $ok = false;
        $messages[] = 'Name cannot be empty!';
    }

    if ($ok) {
        if ($name === 'luka') {
            $ok = true;
            $messages[] = 'Successful login!';
        } else {
            $ok = false;
            $messages[] = 'Incorrect username/password combination!';
        }
    }

    echo json_encode(
        array(
            'ok' => $ok,
            'messages' => $messages
        )
    );

?>
```

In the console I get 2 errors:

1. POST http://127.0.0.1:5500/check-login.php 405 (Method Not Allowed)
2. index.html:36 Could not parse JSON!

Comment: Whatever webserver is running on port 5500 isn't configured to allow POST requests, evidently

Comment: It's 2022, time to start using `fetch()` instead of `XMLHttpRequest`.

Comment: @ADyson I'm just using the live server extention from VS Code. Should I configure that in the json settings somewhere or?

Comment: @Barmar well the tutorial I was watching was from a few years ago, so... And I said I was new to this as well.

Comment: The VS live server can't accept such requests, nor can it execute php code. You need a proper webserver such as Apache or IIS, or at the very least php's built-in  development server